# Windows 7 hanging after a few minutes of use

Tags: freeze, virus

My windows 7 partition (other being mac) has been "hanging" recently. I put hanging in quotes because it's not completely hanging.

Here is what happen. I boot it up and I'll open a program or run something and then after a few minutes I wont be able to run anything. If I am in a game I get disconnected. I can still click on the icons and if I try to open a program from the task bar it looks like it trys to load, but then closes. I can't click on any of the icons in the bottom right corner of the task bar. After a little bit the screen will go black except for my mouse.

The partition is a bit sloppy, but since it has been working for months before this, I do not think that it is the issue.

I believe something is either bugged or I have a virus because this does not occur when I am in safemode.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Goto safe mode and try uninstalling any new software you installed recently

Answer (score 0):

Could be any number of reasons.

It would be worth checking how much space you have allocated to the partition that houses Windows 7, if it's even close to be using up, it's going to slow down the OS.

I would also recommend [downloading Spybot](http://www.safer-networking.org/dl/) and running a full system scan from safe mode, any type of spyware could be causing this the symptons you describe.

You could go the whole hog and run a full virus scan (Avast) and malware scan (Malware Antibytes) from safe mode as well. All recommended software can be downloaded for free.

Failing all of this, there may be corruption within the Windows 7 install on the partition and you could consider operations such as:-

- Windows Repair (from your Windows 7 CD).
- Windows Backup (from previously backed up Windows 7 images).
- Windows System Restore (from previously made restore points).

My first guess would be that the partition doesn't have sufficient resources to be running the OS though.